# Efficient means to poll from a source and update UI on Android?

Tags: android, multithreading, user-interface, android-asynctask, android-intent

I am trying to poll a given website periodically for information and then in turn update the UI in an Android app.

I have set something up similar to the following, but it just seems cumbersome. I guess my two specific questions would be:

1. Is the `view.post(new Runnable());` necessary or are the broadcasts handled on the UI thread (allowing the AsyncTask to be executed directly since it must be done from the UI)?
2. Is there any way to periodically start an AsyncTask (or something comparable) besides setting up the alarms and receiving the Intents?

Here is a simplified version of what I am running:

```
public class WebUpdates extends BroadcastReceiver
{

private AlarmManager am ;
private PendingIntent pi ;
private View view ; 
private Context listener ; 

public WebUpdates(Context listener, View view)
{
    this.listener= listener; 
    this.view = view ;

    am = (AlarmManager)listener.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) ;
    pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast((Context)listener, 0, new Intent("WEBUPDATE"), 0) ;

    am.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, 0, (long)15000, pi) ;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
{
    view.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run()
        {
            new WebUpdateTask().execute() ;
        }
    }) ;
}

private class WebUpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... v) 
    {
        // bunch of web stuff... 
    }

    public void onPostExecute(Void v)
    {
        view.doBunchOfUpdates() ;
    }
}
}
```

This is my first question, so I apologize for for any formatting issues. Any input or help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use alarms?

Comment: @Nanne Not particularly. I am newer to writing serious Android apps and just wasn't sure this was the accepted practice for doing such a task. It just seemed a little cumbersome to me to have the system have to continually create, process, and filter these Intents, as well as manage starting and stopping the alarm when the activity is paused and resumed.
I am probably just over thinking it. The alarm alone is simple enough, and the AsyncTasks are an elegant part of the API in my opinion. I just feel like it seemed verbose when they were put together to do a genuinely simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29), onReceive() exceutes on the main thread.  So you ought to be able to start the AsyncTask directly.
2. Another option would be to use [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html).  There are a number of examples on the web, here is [one](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=728).  AlarmManager is better if you need to receive the Intent even when your Activity is not active.  Timer and TimerTask might be better if you only need the periodic behavior while your Activity is running.  Oh and I guess [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html) is preferred for new code; I've just used Timer/TimerTask in the past.

But I don't think there is any harm in using AlarmManager even if you only need to update when your app is being used, as long as you cancel the alarm in onPause().

Comment: 1. My fault for missing that in the documentation. I apologize and appreciate the clarification!
2. It sounds like AlarmManager would be the proper way to go in the world of Android, especially considering the ability to be a good citizen on the phone by using the inexact alarms. 
I think I was just over thinking it, as they are really two paradigms with very clean solutions to each, and at first just seemed a little disorganized or verbose when used together.

Comment: Accepted this answer on the grounds that the first question was clearly answered, and all options for the second were presented and addressed, with AlarmManager seeming to be the proper solution for this application.